# Bug found while copying file from usb to hdd

Tags: usb, usb-drive

1) It is estimating wrong size to copy. I selected 171.8MB file. It shows 20.8MB to copy

2) Speed starts at 1 mbps. it is ok, but dips till 120 kbps. I am using USB 3 pendrive. This is too low speed

3) If I copy the same via terminal with cp -rf, files copy within few seconds. All files get copy. the exact file size is only 91.5 GB

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Truly funny bug.

Comment: Ok I have added a image to project size is around 1.2 MB that means 90 MB.

Comment: Maybe a bug, maybe not. Some USB drives have very slow memory cells and internal management. Starting/stopping for each file can take long time, so writing many small files will be very slow (a low value for MB/s) compared to writing one single big file. The slowing down is probably because at first the system writes to a buffer, but after it is full, the real write speed to the drive will show. See this link for details, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed

Comment: @sudodus Na, when I did via terminal just in 2.5 sec all files copied. Something really wrong.

Comment: What happens if you run `sync` to flush the buffers? Will the shell return to prompt at once, or will it take some time for `sync` to finish?

Comment: @sudodus I am new to linux. Plz tell the command in details

Comment: Directly after your `cp` command line, you run the command `sync` (no options, no parameters) in the terminal window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66134/discussion-between-aravind-and-sudodus).